# Does Islam specify what to think to get to sleep?

Tags: hadith, practical-islam, source-identification

Is there any Hadith where we are told what we should think about when we have our eyes shut and are trying to get to sleep?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any hadith explaining what one should think about when go to sleep (while eyes are shut and one try to sleep).

The closest hadith would be:

> ... When one of you goes to bed and wants to go to sleep. he should mention Allah Almighty."
>
> [source](https://sunnah.com/urn/2211640)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is an actual hadith, but I have been told since I was 5 years old to

Recite Suratil falaq (Quran:113) and naas (114)

Zhikir: Subahan Allah (10 times)

Alhamdu Lilah  (10 times)

Allahu Akbar (10 times)

It worked for me all my life, seldom had a nightmare.